# Change user input from view before saving in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that accepts a decimal (SQLite3 development database). I want the user to input a string however, for example "1:15:15" (which can be human-read as 1 hour, 15 minutes and 15 seconds, or, 75 minutes and 15 seconds). In my model I have a before_save that calls a custom private method to convert the string to a number (note that using private or not has the same result):

```
class LogEntry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(date: :desc) }
  before_save :convert_runtime

  def convert_runtime
    a = self.runtime.split(':')
    #debugger
    self[:runtime] = a[0].to_f * 3600 + a[1].to_f * 60 + a[2].to_f 
  end
end
```

The split gave me an error so when I inserted the `debugger` code and changed the line with the split to only `a = self.runtime` (to see what this value actually is) the debugger yields a value of `0.1e1` for the "a" variable (a is for array). So what Rails seems to do is convert the first value in the string coming from the user (before the ":") to a decimal, ignoring the remainder of the string, before it's saved. Is there a way to manipulate the entire string as it's passed from the view to the model, without Rails first converting it to decimal form? My next option is to change the database to save the string. I feel like this is less ideal because if I want to add up years of entries, each string needs to be converted to a number first, so I'd rather store the time value as seconds, and convert upon input.

I've been stuck on this one for awhile.

Comment: I don't see errors with your code besides using `a` instead of  `array`, I suppose that's a copy/paste error, btw way `to_i` would be enough in your case, what type is your runtime field in the database?

Comment: runtime type is decimal

Comment: yup Sergio is right, the answer below should fix your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a transient accessor for your string representation, so that activerecord's typing helpers don't cast your value. Something like this:

```
class LogEntry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(date: :desc) }

  attr_accessor :runtime_string

  before_save :convert_runtime

  def convert_runtime
    a = runtime_string.split(':')
    #debugger
    self[:runtime] = a[0].to_f * 3600 + a[1].to_f * 60 + a[2].to_f 
  end
end
```

Naturally, your form must use `runtime_string` now

```
<%= f.text_field :runtime_string %>
```

Comment: for security, should the convert_runtime method be private?

Comment: @Chris That is because records loaded from the database don't have `runtime_string` set. This can be solved by adding a guard clause. `return unless runtime_string`

Comment: This answer works and note that I also had to change "runtime" to "runtime_string" in the params (log entries controller).

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom setter that does not override an existing method. Some would call this a computed attribute.

```
class LogEntry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(date: :desc) }

  def runtime_string
    return unless runtime
    hours, minutes   = runtime.divmod(3600)
    minutes, seconds = minutes.divmod(60)
    [hours, minutes, seconds].drop_while(&:zero?).join(':').presence || '0'
  end

  def runtime_string=(value)
    seconds, minutes, hours = value.split(':').map(&:to_i).reverse
    self.runtime = (seconds || 0) + (minutes || 0) * 60 + (hours || 0) * 3600
  end
end
```

Then use this new getter/setter in your form.

The reason I reverse the split value is to handle both the strings `"10"`, `"1:15"` and `"1:2:34"`. However if you know the input is always `H:M:S` then there is no need to reverse the split output.

Comment: @Chris Have you updated your form to use `runtime_string` instead of `runtime`?

Comment: @Chris Can `runtime` be `nil`? I've updated the answer with a guard clause on the getter.

Comment: Are you using `runtime_string` to assign the string? The only logical reason it would produce `1` if if you passed the string `"1:23:45"` to `runtime`, because `"1:23:45".to_d #=> 1`

Comment: @Chris Did you permit it in the controller? `params.require(:log_entry).permit(:runtime_string, ...)` ?

Comment: I did forget. So this is SOLVED. Thank you! (and I bet Sergio's answer works as well, if I remember the controller!)

Comment: @3, I eliminated my work-through comments so if this question can help another user they see more useful info. I checked Sergio's answer as correct, because I can't check both, those his and yours both work. I think for someone else coming across this question the procedural, less specific, nature of his answer better serves the general question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this works, and doesn't require the `before_save` line:

```
def runtime=(runtime)
   a = runtime.split(":")
   self[:runtime] = a[0].to_f * 3600 + a[1].to_f * 60 + a[2].to_f 
end
```

However, it's not `private` and I'm not sure if this is a security risk.

Comment: it works because you are overwriting the assign command generated by ActiveRecord::Base, which was the problem you had with activerecord converting your data into a BigDecimal value, 0.1e1 is basically BigDecimal.new('1:15:15'.to_i), to answer your question... kinda, as good general rule avoid overwriting or manually creating(use attr_accessor) assigns or retrieves in a model unless you really know what are you doing and the side effects

Comment: Note that this will remove the option to assign a decimal. `log_entry.runtime = 123` does no longer work.