# Rails validate two different regex on one model entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to input a string that is either "h:mm:ss" or "mm:ss" from a view and save it in a model. I figured out the regex and wrote a method in the model as follows:

```
    validate :runtime_came_from_correct_time_entry_format
    
        def runtime_came_from_correct_time_entry_format
          valid_time_format_short = /\A\d{1,2}:\d{2}\z/  # exactly xx:xx OR x:xx like 25:29, 9:50
          valid_time_format_long = /\A\d{1}:\d{2}:\d{2}\z/ # exactly x:xx:xx like 1:25:29 
          errors.add(:time, 'must be in format h:mm:dd, mm:ss, or m:ss') unless
          (:runtime_string =~ valid_time_format_short || :runtime_string =~ valid_time_format_long)
        end
```

I can't bypass the custom error when testing in the view, so I was wondering if I can test two different input types this way in Rails? The regex works in tubular so that is tested.

Comment: runtime_string is the name of the param fm the view that is also permitted in the controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll skip ahead and simply say you should skip your custom validator, and just use the `format` validator with your regexes combined into one:

```
VALID_TIME_FORMAT_SHORT = /\d{1,2}:\d{2}/  # exactly xx:xx OR x:xx like 25:29, 9:50
VALID_TIME_FORMAT_LONG = /\d{1}:\d{2}:\d{2}/ # exactly x:xx:xx like 1:25:29 

VALID_TIME_FORMAT = /\A(#{VALID_TIME_FORMAT_SHORT}|#{VALID_TIME_FORMAT_LONG})\z/

validates :runtime_string, format: { with: VALID_TIME_FORMAT }
```

You should in any case move your error message into your local file, rather than have English strings embedded in your models.

If you want to salvage your custom validation method, you can't use parenthesis to produce "or" matches in the form `x =~ (a || b)`, that isn't how boolean operators and parenthesis interact. You need `x =~ a || x =~ b`.

You also appear to be testing the symbol `:runtime_string`, not the actual value, which is not likely intentional.

Comment: I noticed the tragic logic error you pointed out in the custom method (fixing this, it still did not work, however). Your solution does work well and I was also looking at Rubular.com and playing around with a single regex that does what I want, which is a good way to go, too.

Comment: I think you're probably going to want to skip regex for this, really. You're accepting things like `99:99` or `0:00:00` as times

Comment: those both pass and save properly. Here's some context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64395179/change-user-input-from-view-before-saving-in-model